# Params is confusing with a endpoint name, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont know when i printed params i am getting the endpoint name as an action 'change_state', i am using a custom route, action have as a value 'change_state', the correct value should be 'playing'

```
def change_state
    puts params
```

i am getting this:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"action"=>"change_state", "controller"=>"v1/sports", "sport_id"=>"5", "sport"=>{}} permitted: false>
```

the statement of the route is like his:

```
resources :sports do
          post '/change_state', to: 'sports#next_state'
```

this is my url that i am using in potsman

```
http://localhost:8110/.../sports/5/change_state
```

and as a body i am sending

```
{
 state: 'playing'
}
```

Comment: it looks correct to me. What is the entire params hash? it should have `state: 'playing` included, does it?

Comment: @LesNightingill i need this: #<ActionController::Parameters {"action"=>"playing", how can i get playing, i can see any hash param

Comment: Show us the entirety of your controller maybe

Comment: you have specified the action to be 'change_state` in your routes file... so that's what you are getting. If you send `state: 'playing'` in the body, this is received in the parameters hash in the `change_state` action. If you are putting `state: 'playing'` in the body and expecting that action, you are mistaken... it's data passed to the controller action ('change_state') that you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is behaving correctly. The `params` always contains an `action` that matches the controller method routed to.  This  is the normal behavior in Rails and provides you with a way of knowing which "action" is being processed. *(see further explanation below)*

**Have you tried inspecting the params for the `state` key?** The output you listed in the question seems like it was cut-off, it's possible if you inspected via a debugger you'd find the expected key.  You could also print it as a hash via `puts params.to_unsafe_hash`

---

###### Further explanation of the `action` key on params:

As an example in a fresh app, using a StaticController with the route and controller:

```rb
# routes.rb
root "static#home"
  
# controllers/static_controller.rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
    puts params
  end
  ...
```

When you visit `http://localhost:3000/` you'll see it print: `{"controller"=>"static", "action"=>"home"}`

If you visit `http://localhost:3000/?state=exuberant`, you'll see it print:
`{"state"=>"exuberant", "controller"=>"static", "action"=>"home"}`

Comment: then action is a reserved word right?

Comment: You could definitely think of it that way.  But it's not going to raise an exception like using a reserved word would in some languages.  If you go to `http://localhost:3000/?action=flight`, you'll see it print: `{"action"=>"home", "controller"=>"static"}`.  It silently replaced the original `action` param you passed in, but you could still get them from `request.query_parameters` (I would not recommend doing this though).  Also worth noting, I've used query parameters for simplicity but I see you're doing a POST and might be using form params instead.

Comment: it is reserved in the way that it will always contain the action name of the controller being executed. Same for `controller` and `format`. Avoid using those names as your parameter names and it should be good.